# Swift: How to import other files to your app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am developing a file manager app , and I need to users able to import other files to my application, I searched many question but did not success !

First I register file types using : [Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1),

[image]

But when I tap share icon on safari or photos there my app won't show in list of apps.
And then what is the next step to import files and store it to `Document Directory` of my app?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS other apps will not just automatically communicate with your app. You have to create an extension that lets the other apps like Safari or Photos know that your app can talk to them. A basic description for this can be found in the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html).

There they also point you towards sources on how to work with the iOS file system.